# F8 the first time evaluates line in PowerShell, not in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

## Demonstration of Issue

I open a new python file:

```
code -n C:\temp\test-a.py
```

The contents of the file:

[image]

If I move the cursor to the line with `10` on it and press `F8` I see the following in the terminal window:

[image]

Note that the `10` wasn't evaluated in Python, but in PowerShell.

If I hit `F8` again on that line:

[image]

now it's evaluated in Python.

## Question

Is this a bug? Shouldn't the initial `F8` cause the line to be evaluated in Python, not PowerShell?

## Misc

`Help: About`:

[image]

## Debugging info

After enabling `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting`, and pressing `F8`, the following is generated in the `OUTPUT` window:

```
2023-12-22 06:58:38.027 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving F8
2023-12-22 06:58:38.028 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 5 keybinding entries, matched python.execSelectionInTerminal, when: editorTextFocus && !findInputFocussed && !jupyter.ownsSelection && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python', source: user.
2023-12-22 06:58:38.028 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: F8, keyCode: 119, key: F8
2023-12-22 06:58:38.029 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: F8, keyCode: 66 ('F8')
2023-12-22 06:58:38.030 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving F8
2023-12-22 06:58:38.030 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 5 keybinding entries, matched python.execSelectionInTerminal, when: editorTextFocus && !findInputFocussed && !jupyter.ownsSelection && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python', source: user.
2023-12-22 06:58:38.031 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Invoking command python.execSelectionInTerminal.
2023-12-22 06:58:40.678 [error] TextModelPart is disposed!: Error: TextModelPart is disposed!
    at d.g (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:121:22451)
    at d.getWordAtPosition (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:631:119008)
    at W.getWordAtPosition (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:736:9056)
    at k.h (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:760:68470)
    at new $ (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:760:68345)
    at new k (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:760:69207)
    at D (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:760:69734)
    at O.G (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:760:74294)
    at O.F (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:760:74091)
    at new O (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:760:70761)
    at q (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:760:75166)
    at u.value (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:760:75311)
    at f.y (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:1902)
    at f.z (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:1972)
    at f.fire (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:2188)
    at x.setModel (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:744:400)
    at k.setInput (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2396:11447)
    at async k.setInput (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/dharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2400:3886)
```

## Updated vscode

```
Version: 1.84.2 (user setup)
Commit: 1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e
Date: 2023-11-09T10:51:52.184Z
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: 24603566
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
```

## First press of `F8`

```
2023-12-22 19:29:15.355 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving F8
2023-12-22 19:29:15.356 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 5 keybinding entries, matched python.execSelectionInTerminal, when: editorTextFocus && !findInputFocussed && !jupyter.ownsSelection && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python', source: user.
2023-12-22 19:29:15.357 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: F8, keyCode: 119, key: F8
2023-12-22 19:29:15.357 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: F8, keyCode: 66 ('F8')
2023-12-22 19:29:15.358 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving F8
2023-12-22 19:29:15.359 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 5 keybinding entries, matched python.execSelectionInTerminal, when: editorTextFocus && !findInputFocussed && !jupyter.ownsSelection && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python', source: user.
2023-12-22 19:29:15.360 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Invoking command python.execSelectionInTerminal.
```

Terminal output:

```
PS C:\Users\dharm> 10
10
PS C:\Users\dharm> C:/Users/dharm/miniconda3/Scripts/activate
PS C:\Users\dharm> conda activate base
PS C:\Users\dharm> & C:/Users/dharm/miniconda3/python.exe
Python 3.10.11 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, May 16 2023, 00:55:32) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

## Second press of `F8`

```
2023-12-22 19:30:49.235 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving F8
2023-12-22 19:30:49.235 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 5 keybinding entries, matched python.execSelectionInTerminal, when: editorTextFocus && !findInputFocussed && !jupyter.ownsSelection && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python', source: user.
2023-12-22 19:30:49.236 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: F8, keyCode: 119, key: F8
2023-12-22 19:30:49.236 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: F8, keyCode: 66 ('F8')
2023-12-22 19:30:49.237 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving F8
2023-12-22 19:30:49.237 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 5 keybinding entries, matched python.execSelectionInTerminal, when: editorTextFocus && !findInputFocussed && !jupyter.ownsSelection && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python', source: user.
2023-12-22 19:30:49.238 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Invoking command python.execSelectionInTerminal.
```

Terminal output:

```
>>> 10
10
>>>
```

Comment: 2) the `Help: About` command has a "copy" button to copy as text. Please use the text instead of an image (see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541). 3) Is the output you've shown for keybinding troubleshooting for the first time you press F8? Or the second time? I want to see the output for _both_ times. 3) Please add the version number of your Python extension.

Comment: 4) After adding the above info to your question post, I'm also curious if this still happens if you update to the latest version of VS Code, and if it still happens after that, if it still happens if you switch to the insiders channel of the Python extension.

Comment: @starball Thank you for your help and for your patience! I've updated vscode and posted the new `About` text. I've also added the keyboard logging and terminal output for the first and second `F8` presses.

Comment: @starball Correct, the error trace is no longer there.

Comment: What order does your `F8` bind? Have you tried `Shift+Enter`?

Comment: I didn't say from the beginning, but I've actually been able to reproduce this behaviour. I just raised a bug report: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22691

Answer (score 1):

I raised an issue ticket on the extension's GitHub repo (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22691) and a maintainer just pushed a change to the pre-release channel that should reduce the chances of this kind of problem happening ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22691#issuecomment-1949407784)). If you have more problems like this in the future, you can raise another issue ticket (remember to provide a [minimal reproducible example](/help/mre)).